# DOM elements with overflow hidden and child elements within them, can the DOM measure the height/width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a slider of sorts, and I am having a bit of trouble calculating the height and width of some children elements that fall outside of the defined area of the parent block element. They are in the hidden area of it in a matter of speaking.

So I am trying to figure out if elements in that void suffer a similar fate to elements styled with `display:none` where the javascript running with the DOM can't detect the height or width of them even if styled with a height and width, it treats it as if the element didn't exist for the most part in that aspect. Elements that are currently in my hidden void are not styled with `display:none`.

So, is it maybe something I doing or is it that they do suffer that fate?

Comment: Could you please try splitting your longest sentence into smaller ones? I was trying to edit it but wasn't sure how to do it without breaking the meaning. Extremely long sentences hurt.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide jsffidle

Answer (score 1):

I believe elements inside a parent with `overflow: hidden` are still rendered completely and have detectable, accurate dimensions - even when they do overflow their parents. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/napple/DLKVG/) to that effect.

There may be some cases where this is not true. If so, then it is dependent on styling.

Comment: In particular, `overflow: hidden` simply hides the overflow visually. For example you can still force the parent to scroll to its hidden children using JavaScript `scrollTop` and/or `scrollLeft`. This is why the layout of child elements is not affected.